# Fos elastica get code name in code table

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I am using fosElastica for populate at elasticsearch. I have a two entity, that entities relationship together.

But I couldn't populate and show category name in products index. How can I to do?

Entity/AirportCodes.php

```
/**
 * @var string $AirportCode
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="AirportCode", type="string", length=3)
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="XXXBundle\Entity\AirportCodesTrans")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="AirportCode", referencedColumnName="airport_code", nullable=false)
 */
private $airportCode;
```

Services.yml

```
example-connect:
    properties:
        AirportCode: { type: text, analyzer: autocomplete }
        AirportSlug: ~
        CountryCode: ~
        CityCode: ~
    persistence:
        driver: orm
        model: XXXBundle\Entity\AirportCodes
        identifier: AirportCode
        provider: ~
        finder: ~
```

Entity/AirportCodesTrans

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $AirportCode
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="airport_code", type="string", length=3)
 */
private $airportCode;

/**
 * @var string $lang
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lang", type="string", length=3)
 */
private $lang;

/**
 * @var string $name
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;
```

Comment: But you don't have product and category anywhere in your code

Comment: I changed title. I forgot this at first. @hanishsingla

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/zijc/populating-elasticsearch-index-with-a-custom-provider-service-without-having-a-database), [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/a1cx/using-a-custom-query-builder-method-provider-to-populate-elasticsearch-index-with-manually-selected-data-from-database) and [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/43pu/programatically-populating-elasticsearch-index-in-symfony). See if they help in any way.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it via this link. (http://obtao.com/blog/2014/05/advanced-indexing-with-elasticsearch-foselasticabundle/)

Comment: I missed [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ji7r/manually-creating-and-manipulating-elasticsearch-index-with-a-custom-model-to-elastica-transformer-service) / [in your language!](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/yazi/x8kr/ozel-bir-model-to-elastica-transformer-service-ile-elasticsearch-index-yaratmak-veya-indexi-manipule-etmek) one which is what your link does.

Comment: Need transform to me. Your link is very helpfull too.I didn't see. Thank you very much.